# truncate command to to safely remove Celery log files?

Tags: truncate

I my Ubuntu server that is running Python/Celery has about 9 log files totaling to 9GB space.

Is it safe to reduce the size of these files by running the following command?

> truncate -s 0 *log

If not, is there any other suggestions to reduce the size of these files?